# How to Filter JSON object in Android in accordance with another value of object?

Tags: android, json

I've json object like this:

**JSon Object**

```
{
      "31": {
        "basic": {
          "node_id": "31",
          "title": "test",
          "alias": "test",
          "description": "test",
          "site_id": "151336557",
          "node_type": "7",
          "privacy": "7",
          "deleted": "0",
          "status": "1",
          "created_date": "1379169518",
          "updated_date": "1379169518",
          "created_by": "140513626519686828",
          "updated_by": null,
          "readable_date": "14th Sep, 2013"
        },
        "meta": {
          "forum_id": "61"
        },
        "comments": {
          "count": 1
        },
        "likes": {
          "count": 0
        },
        "tags": [],
        "node_id": "31"
      },
      "32": {
        "basic": {
          "node_id": "32",
          "title": "testing discussion",
          "alias": "testing-discussion",
          "description": "testing",
          "site_id": "151336557",
          "node_type": "7",
          "privacy": "7",
          "deleted": "0",
          "status": "1",
          "created_date": "1379493816",
          "updated_date": "1379493816",
          "created_by": "140513795022034166",
          "updated_by": null,
          "readable_date": "18th Sep, 2013"
        },
        "meta": {
          "forum_id": "65"
        },
        "comments": {
          "count": 1
        },
        "likes": {
          "count": 0
        },
        "tags": [],
        "node_id": "32"
      }     
}
```

and this is the code that I want to get certain object:

```
           arrayTemplist = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

            for(int x=0;x<feedItems.size();x++)
            {

                int currentNodeType =feedItems.get(x).getNode_type();

                if (currentNodeType!=0 && currentNodeType==nodeType)
                {
                    arrayTemplist.add(feedItems.get(x));
                    Log.d("Cem", arrayTemplist.toString());
                }
                else{


                    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
                }


            }

            listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, arrayTemplist);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

            }
```

I am not able to display the view for the filtered data. I can log the data but I am not able to display it.

The whole code is here http://pastie.org/9662511

Comment: I don't really understand what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not set the adapter every iteration. Secondly, you should call notifyDataSetChanged method of the BaseAdapter to refresh the data displayed in the list view.

```
       arrayTemplist = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        for(int x=0;x<feedItems.size();x++)
        {

            int currentNodeType =feedItems.get(x).getNode_type();

            if (currentNodeType!=0 && currentNodeType==nodeType)
            {
                arrayTemplist.add(feedItems.get(x));
                Log.d("Cem", arrayTemplist.toString());
            }
        }

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, arrayTemplist);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()            
        }
```

Comment: I am able to log the data but not able to display it to the view for case:1 (news) [com.sri.vaave.data.FeedItem@527f95f0, com.sri.vaave.data.FeedItem@527f9680, com.sri.vaave.data.FeedItem@527f96e0, com.sri.vaave.data.FeedItem@527f9710, com.sri.vaave.data.FeedItem@527f9740]

Comment: I don't get what are yo trying got say but if it does not work, you should check your adapter implementation.

Comment: Still I think that if you remove the else statement inside the for loop and add the notifyDataSetChanged method to your code after update the data, it will work. However, you should use view holders for the list view in order to have a better performance.

Comment: I tried removing the else statement inside the loop and added the notifyDataSetChanged but it is not working.